# Need to remove Oracle Favicon

Tags: oracle, favicon

[image]

It seems that Oracle favicon is set to my web server as default.

I know how to change favicon in html like this :

`<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/img/common/myFavicon.ico">`

but I need to remove this setting(No default favicon) on server side. Where can I set this?

There are many sites running on this web server, so I want to make every sites changed at once.

The web server's OS is `AIX 5L V5.3` and `iPlanet 7.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the iPlanet settings.

Select a site in `Configuration` tab(** Note that every terms I use in here may not be correct in English. I translated Koreans into English on my own).

Then go to `General` > `Advanced search` > `HTTP setting`.

And see if the `Favorite icon` is checked. It should be NOT checked, if you don't want to show the Oracle favicon. 
[image]

And restart the instance! :)

Answer (score 2):

The favicon should be present at

```
    $oracle_home\Apache\Apache\htdocs
```

You can confirm that by viewing source of the HTML & see what filename `<link rel="shortcut icon"` refers to. Moving the favicon away from that should not should the favicon anymore.

Comment: @Deckard It should be just favicon.ico. You can confirm that by viewing source of the HTML & see what filename `<link rel="shortcut icon"` refers to

Comment: The oracle favicon still appears but I can't confirm it from the HTML. And I looked for all `.ico` files but couldn't find the oracle favicon(I downloaded and checked it one by one).

Comment: Well, I finally found and renamed it but still appearing. Is it because of cache of webserver or something?

Comment: @Deckard Yes, that's possible. Try opening in private browsing mode.

Comment: It stays the same in private browsing mode. I heard that there's something like cache on the server.

Comment: @Deckard so was it a caching issue?

Comment: I'm not sure for that. Maybe I have to contact to IBM or somewhere. Thank you for supporting me :)

Comment: check my own answer. My coworker has just found it! It works perfect:)

Comment: @Deckard great, thanks! You should change the accepted answer to yours!