# Deactivate/change default favicon in iPlanet 6.0

Tags: webserver, favicon, sunone, iplanet

While there are many questions here about a favicon not showing, I have one that is showing out of nowhere...

If I type in my browser `http://localhost`, I see the root of the web directory and no favicon.ico is there. Yet an icon shows up on the browser tab. If I type `http://localhost/favicon.ico`, the browser does show me the icon!

How can `http://localhost/favicon.ico` return something that does not exist?
I am using an iPlanet server linked to weblogic app container.

I searched for a favicon.ico in my entire web directory and weblogic domain, didn't find any (or rather: some others lying around but not the one I see).
I even searched for the string 'favicon.ico' in domain, web directory and iPlanet directory, in case it is in some configuration file, didn't find anything.

Any hint?

Edit: As pointed out by Sacha below, this is a default icon of the server. I would like to know where in the config it is located, and how to deactivate it. I found how to do that in documentation of iPlanet 7.0, but I am using iPlanet 6.0 and I can't find anything in the doc.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no favicon.ico server displays a default one.It might be a xampp or wamp logo.If you want to customize put yours in your project root directory. Eg:- If your project name is saas put it in saas folder.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed a default favicon given by the web server. However I would like to find where it's from. As I said I am using iPlanet (6.0), not a xampp or wamp package.

Comment: Try searching ico in the folder where it is installed.

Comment: Nope. I had already tried searching for various possibilities such .ico, icon, ico, favicon, fav, etc. Both in file names and contents.

Comment: Check this out it might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257066/need-to-remove-oracle-favicon

Comment: Yes I had seen this question. Unfortunately it applies only to iPlanet 7. I have posted the question in Oracle forum, waiting for a reply. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If going to localhost/favicon.ico shows you the icon, then it is there. I am not sure why it is not in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem in jBoss server of my jsp project in which the browser was showing by default server icon and there was no favicon.ico in my whole project directory
then i searched for the favicon on the server and it was there so i have remove that file from the server to remove any default favicon from my project.